# how to solve Ajax post request show 500 (Internal Server Error) in laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

In my project i want to store data in to database using ajax but when i submit the post request it show the error like (500 (Internal Server Error)) i google it several time but still same issue 
this is my ajax code

```
$.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

$('#form-insert').on('submit', function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          var data = $(this).serialize();
          var url = $(this).attr('action');
          var post = $(this).attr('method');
          $.ajax({
            type: post,
            url: url,
            data:{
                   _token: '{!! csrf_token() !!}',
                   data
                 },
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(data){
              console.log(data)
            }
          })
        })
```

this is my view

```
<form method="post" id="form-insert" action="{{ URL::to('item/store')}}">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name">
    </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="text">Email address:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="contact_no">Contact No:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contact_no">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="add">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

this is my route

```
Route::post('/item/store', 'AjaxCrudController@store');
```

this is my controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->ajax()){
            $item = AjaxCrud::create($request->all());
            return response($item);
            //return response($request->all());
        }
    }
```

Comment: An internal server error will usually be logged by your server. You need to find that log file and see what the error is before anyone can help you.

Comment: Can we see the details of the error? You can get them from `storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: Are you sure that this `{ _token: '{!! csrf_token() !!}', data }` produces the correct result?

Comment: sure this will show correct result

Comment: storage/logs/laravel.log show the errorGeneral error: 1364 Field 'name' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `ajax_cruds` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2018-03-23 15:04:25, 2018-03-23 15:04:25))

Comment: The submitted data will be: `{ _token: ..., data: { name: ..., email: ..., contact_no: ... } }`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert the data you are submitting in your ajax request:

```
data:{
   _token: '{!! csrf_token() !!}',
   data
}
```

That means that you are trying to create an `AjaxCrud` resource containing two keys: `_token` and `data`. I suppose that you just want to store the data contained into the `data` object, that is your serialized form and should contain a `name` attribute.

So you have multiple solutions, the first one is to create your AjaxCrud resource from the data object:

```
$item = AjaxCrud::create($request->get('data'));
```

The other solution is to send only the data you want in your ajaxRequest, and set your CSRF token into the headers of your request.